# How to have a multipage-multiple tour site using intro.js?

Tags: javascript, intro.js

I'm currently new to intro js and I have this big project up

I need to start a tour on page 1, that will continue on page 2, then it needs to go back to page 1 and start another tour that will continue on page 3

I hope someone can help me :(

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/usablica/intro.js

There is a multi-page demo in the `examples/` folder.

- Clone the project, open `examples/index.html` file with your browser.
- Click `Multi-Page introduction` and view the source.

At the bottom you will find

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = function() {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next page').start().oncomplete(function() {
      window.location.href = 'second.html?multipage=true';
    });
  };
</script>
```

- Use that to get started.
- Post example code to github or something.
- Update your question when you get stuck.

Comment: where is the link?

Comment: Great point!  I added a link to intro.js on Github  https://github.com/usablica/intro.js  I assume that is it.